Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: and Advertising not working and Permission denied
I am running Raspbery PI 5 with Python and trying to get my android/MIT/Bluetooth/python stack proof of concept tested, but my python bluetooth test code says no advertising available and
sdptool browse local
gives Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is what solved it for me in 2024

edit the blootooth.service file:
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat
and

run this just because everyone else did
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/sdp

edit the /etc/rc.local file
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
Add the commands before the exit 0 line:
/usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 up
/usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 piscan

Make sure the rc.local file is executable:
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local

reboot

If you run the bluetooth test commands from Thonny, you will get permission denied so run from command prompt using sudo first, ie:
sudo python3 /user/home/{path to your test file.py}

to fix sdptool browse local, simply run
sudo sdptool browse local
instead.


